# Visual studio code snippet choices and variables

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I am writing my own snippet to console.log

```
{  
  "Print to console": {
    "scope": "javascript,typescript",
    "prefix": "debug",
    "body": [
      "console.log('${1|[Debug],[Server],[$TM_FILENAME]|}','${2:~Line: $TM_LINE_NUMBER ~ File:$TM_FILENAME}',${3:$TM_SELECTED_TEXT}); //debug",
      "$4"
    ],
    "description": "Log output to console"
  }
}
```

Everything is ok except instead of file name static text TM_FILENAME is getting displayed in choices for placeholder '$1'
`${1|[Debug],[Server],[$TM_FILENAME]|}`.
How can I make filename to be displayed here?
Thanks for suggestions

Comment: It seems like you choices don't support variables. As far as the [provided grammar suggests](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_grammar), choices can only be text.

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87949 No variables in snippet choices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although you cannot directly use variables in a snippet choice, you can workaround it like this:

```
  "Print to console": {
    "scope": "javascript,typescript",
    "prefix": "debug",
    "body": [

      // moved brackets in the choice
      "console.log('[${1|Debug,Server],fileName|}]','${2:~Line: $TM_LINE_NUMBER ~ File:$TM_FILENAME}',${3:$TM_SELECTED_TEXT}); //debug",
      "$4"
    ],
    "description": "Log output to console"
  },

  "getfileName": {
    "scope": "javascript,typescript",
    "prefix": "fileName",   // <= same exact prefix as appears in the choice above
    "body": [
      "$TM_FILENAME"
    ],
    "description": "get the file name"
  }
```

The idea being that the `fileName` choice is actually another snippet that you can trigger after making the choice.  After you select `fileName` you will have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to bring up the second snippet.  It is a little more work but it does allow you to get "variable-like" behaviour in a snippet choice.  And in the second snippet you can add or modify the file name however you like.

Also, sometimes you have to modify the choice a bit.  I modified yours but the output is the same.  Otherwise `[fileName]` is printed and that won't be seen as a match for the other `fileName` prefix.  Although in your case, you could leave it as :

```
"console.log('${1|[Debug],[Server],[fileName]|}','${2:~Line: $TM_LINE_NUMBER ~ File:$TM_FILENAME}',${3:$TM_SELECTED_TEXT}); //debug",
```

in the first snippet and then make the second prefix like so:

```
"prefix": "fileName]",  // note the trailing bracket
```

Same result, just be aware to adjust the second prefix to match what is actually printed out by the choice selection or it won't work.

[image: snippet choice variable]